# Should I index 404.html in my "sitemap.xml" file?

Tags: 404, xml-sitemap

I'm a beginner with websites and I want to know if the `sitemap.xml` file of my website should or shouldn't index the `404.html` page, which is a custom 404 page.

This question is quite similar to [Should 404 pages feature in your sitemap.xml](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49615/should-404-pages-feature-in-your-sitemap-xml) but that question felt very vague to me and it didn't clearly state what I'm supposed to do if I have a custom 404 page. Though there was a short comment about it, yet I need to verify that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

404 Pages exist to let the users/browsers know that the page does not exist. There is no reason or need to index a 404 page. As long as your 404 page passes the error code, it is fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems reasonable to me now to not to index the 404 page.